# How to run tags using AND operation from command line using karate.options

Tags: karate

Feature file

```
Feature: Tags feature

  @smoke @regression
  Scenario: create user using post and inline json payload
    Given url 'https://reqres.in/api'
    And path '/users'
    And request {"name": "morpheus","job": "leader"}
    When method post
    Then status 201
    * match response.name == "morpheus"
    * match response.job == "leader"
    * print 'Tags feature:@smoke, method post'
```

Command used:

```
mvn test -Dkarate.options='-t=@smoke -t=@regression' -Dtest=SampleTest
```

```
mvn test "-Dkarate.options=--tags {"@smoke","@regression"}" -Dtest=SampleTest
```

First command is working. But second is not. How can I make the second command working?

Comment: Worked using the command mvn test "-Dkarate.options=--tags @smoke --tags @regression" -Dtest=SampleTest